# Excel Formula SUMIF Secondary Criteria For Only Positive Numbers

Tags: excel

I have 2 tables - one with data and one that performs calculations on the data. Until now, in my first table - Check  - I had this formula:

```
SUMIF(visual!A:A,check!A2,visual!AB:AB)
```

But now in column AB, I have negative numbers, and I need to sum just the positive numbers in the same way I did it before. I need to write a formula that will sum only the positive numbers in AB and not sum the whole column if the sum total is bigger than 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You’re looking for the `SUMIFS` function. You would use it like this:

```
SUMIFS(visual!AB:AB, visual!A:A, check!A2, visual!AB:AB, ">0")
```

[The documentation](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIFS-function-c9e748f5-7ea7-455d-9406-611cebce642b) shows its syntax and gives these examples:

> `SUMIFS(sum_range, criteria_range1, criteria1, [criteria_range2, criteria2], ...)`
>
> - `=SUMIFS(A2:A9,B2:B9,"=A*",C2:C9,"Tom")`
> - `=SUMIFS(A2:A9,B2:B9,"<>Bananas",C2:C9,"Tom")`

Note that the order of parameters is different from [`SUMIF`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIF-function-169b8c99-c05c-4483-a712-1697a653039b), which has the syntax `SUMIF(range, criteria, [sum_range])`.